# Updating Gulp plugins

Tags: dependencies, npm, yeoman, gulp, yeoman-generator

When starting a project using a Yeoman generator, say, `generator-gulp-webapp`, you get a `package.json` file with all the dependencies.

Is it recommended to update all or any of these dependencies (ex: `gulp-useref`, `gulp-ruby-sass`, `gulp-bower-files`, etc)? What are the implications of doing or not doing so?

Comment: thanks for the -1, now I'd love to find the reason for it

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It is always necessary to update your plugins, as the syntax keeps changing as and then you keep going ahead.

Here’s what I recommend to fix it:

1) `npm install -g npm-check-updates`

2) `npm-check-updates -u`

3) `rm -fr node_modules`

4) `npm install`

Basically this installs npm-check-updates globally, runs it against your package.json and updates the dependency versions. Then you just delete the node modules folder and re-install.

Comment: done that...21 packages updated! i knew that a lot stuff would break, but fortunately it was no big deal to fix them. anyway, `package.json` is under source control. thanks!

Comment: Is `rm -fr node_modules` necessary if only 1 or 2 modules was updated?
Is there not a more efficient way to this?

Comment: I think that after using `npm-check-updates -u` , you can only run `npm update`. Correct me if I am wrong please.

Comment: @shaneparsons - I do not think it is necessary to run the `rm` command. The `npm install` step should take care of cleaning your packages.